# Using templated class in templated class c++

Tags: c++, templates

I have to implement a data structure in multiple different ways, each of which should be compatible with using multiple data types.

I then have to make a class that can test all of these implementations using different data types.

Example:

```
Testobject obj = Testobject<DatastructType1<int>>();
Testobject obj2 = Testobject<DatastructType2<float>>();
```

I have tried multiple ways to use the correct syntax for the Testobject class.

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Testobject {
    public:
        Testobject();

    private:
        T<U> data;

};
```

It looks like this now, but instead of this first line I have also tried the following:

```
template <typename T <typename U>>

template <typename T, template <typename> class U>>

template <template <typename T> class U>
```

So basically I'm wondering what the right syntax is.

EDIT: my lecturer just simplified the assignment, so this is no longer necessary. However, if anyone has a solution, I'm still curious.

Answer (score 2):

You have several choices depending of the syntax expected:

```
template <typename T>
class Testobject {
public:
    Testobject();

private:
    T data;
};

Testobject obj = Testobject<DatastructType1<int>>();
Testobject obj2 = Testobject<DatastructType2<float>>();
```

or

```
template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
class Testobject
{
public:
    Testobject();

private:
    C<T> data;
};

Testobject obj = Testobject<DatastructType1, int>();
Testobject obj2 = Testobject<DatastructType2, float>();
```

A variant of first snippet, with partial specialization:

```
template <typename T> class Testobject;

template <template <typename> class C, typename T>
class Testobject<C<T>>
{
public:
    Testobject();

private:
    C<T> data;
};

Testobject obj = Testobject<DatastructType1<int>>();
Testobject obj2 = Testobject<DatastructType2<float>>();
```